# Lighting objects with different colors and intensity

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm making a game where the player need to fly through rings to earn points. I want to use different lights for my ship, rings and a light for the scene. I'm having issues with lighting these three things. If I run the code with three funtion calls in main.cpp only the first gets properly lighted. If I comment the first out the second gets executed and so on, but never all three.

World.cpp

```
glm::vec4 lightPositionWorld = Model * glm::vec4(.0f, 20.0f, -30.0f, 1.0f);  
glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(programID, "LightPositionWorld"), lightPositionWorld.x, lightPositionWorld.y, lightPositionWorld.z);
```

Ship.cpp

```
glm::vec3 lightPositionSpaceShip = glm::vec3(.0, 7.0, .0);
glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(programID, "LightPositionSpaceShip"), lightPositionSpaceShip.x, lightPositionSpaceShip.y, lightPositionSpaceShip.z);
```

Gate.cpp

```
glm::vec3 lightPositionGate = glm::vec3(5.0, 3.0, .0);
glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(programID, "LightPositionGate"), lightPositionGate.x, lightPositionGate.y, lightPositionGate.z);
```

SimpleFragmentShader.fragmentshader

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 UV;
in vec3 Position_worldspace;
in vec3 Normal_cameraspace;
in vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace;
in vec3 LightDirectionCameraWorld;
in vec3 LightDirectionCameraSpaceShip;
in vec3 LightDirectionCameraGate;

out vec3 colorWorld;
out vec3 colorSpaceShip;
out vec3 colorGate;

uniform sampler2D objectTexture;
uniform vec3 LightPositionWorld;
uniform vec3 LightPositionSpaceShip;
uniform vec3 LightPositionGate;

vec3 lighting(float red, float green, float blue, float power, vec2 UV, vec3 Position_worldspace, vec3 Normal_cameraspace, vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace, vec3 LightDirectionCamera, vec3 LightPosition)
{ 
    vec3 LightColor = vec3(red, green, blue);
    float LightPower = power; 
    vec3 MaterialDiffuseColor = texture(objectTexture, UV ).rgb;
    vec3 MaterialAmbientColor = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3) * MaterialDiffuseColor; 
    vec3 MaterialSpecularColor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    float distance = length( LightPosition - Position_worldspace );
    vec3 normal = normalize(Normal_cameraspace);
    vec3 light = normalize(LightDirectionCamera);
    float cosTheta = clamp(dot(normal, light), .0, 1.0);

    vec3 eye = normalize(EyeDirection_cameraspace);
    vec3 reflect = reflect(-light, normal);
    float cosAlpha = clamp( dot(eye, reflect), .0, 1.0);    
    vec3 color =    MaterialAmbientColor + 
                    MaterialDiffuseColor * LightColor * LightPower * cosTheta / (distance * distance) +
                    MaterialSpecularColor * LightColor * LightPower * pow(cosAlpha, 5) / (distance * distance);

    return color;
}

void main()
{
    colorWorld = lighting(0.81f, 0.71f, 0.23f, 90.0f, UV, Position_worldspace, Normal_cameraspace, EyeDirection_cameraspace, LightDirectionCameraWorld, LightPositionWorld);
    colorSpaceShip = lighting(0.329412f, 0.329412f, 0.329412f, 90.0f, UV, Position_worldspace, Normal_cameraspace, EyeDirection_cameraspace, LightDirectionCameraSpaceShip, LightPositionSpaceShip);
    colorGate = lighting(0.81f, 0.71f, 0.23f, 90.0f, UV, Position_worldspace, Normal_cameraspace, EyeDirection_cameraspace, LightDirectionCameraGate, LightPositionGate);
}
```

I expect the scene and two objects lighted in different color and intensity.

Comment: What is this odd syntax: `in vec2 UV;` ? Never seen that. Doesn't seem correct up to me.

Comment: That is exactly the OpenGL tutorial syntax for the fragmentshader.

Comment: @kebs That's normal GLSL syntax.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I learned something (I only do bare C++).

Comment: You're outputting 3 different colors. How do you expect those to end up applying to the 3 different objects you're drawing? Also, how are you drawing your geometry?

Comment: I assume that you have a single color buffer, because you render to the default framebuffer and didn't create a framebuffer which 3 color buffers, isn't it? The solution is described in the answer of @AndyBarcia. Use 1 output int the fragment shader, sum the return values of `lighting` function and assign it to the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the behaviour you are expecting you shouldn't output multiple colors, you should output a single color per fragment: 
`out vec4 fragColor;`
Then the simplest way to correct your code would be adding the 3 different lighting results:

```
fragColor = vec4(lighting(0.81f, 0.71f, 0.23f, 90.0f, UV, Position_worldspace, Normal_cameraspace, EyeDirection_cameraspace, LightDirectionCameraWorld, LightPositionWorld) +
        lighting(0.329412f, 0.329412f, 0.329412f, 90.0f, UV, Position_worldspace, Normal_cameraspace, EyeDirection_cameraspace, LightDirectionCameraSpaceShip, LightPositionSpaceShip) +
        lighting(0.81f, 0.71f, 0.23f, 90.0f, UV, Position_worldspace, Normal_cameraspace, EyeDirection_cameraspace, LightDirectionCameraGate, LightPositionGate), 1.0);
```

Also in your lighting method the `MaterialAmbientColor` should also be attenuated with distance, otherwise the ambient light would be added 3 times when calculating the final color.